# AltCoins based on Scrypt - How to do transactions with PHP?

Tags: litecoin, scrypt, altcoin

Im interested in other scrypt based coins other than Litecoin.

I have noticed that most of these coins have no documentation. So is it safe to assume that I can follow the Litecoin documentation if I have a question about a function or feature of said other scrypt based coin?

Second, I cant find anything about using PHP and doing transactions with Litecoins or any other coins (just javascript). Can anybody point me to some examples of how to do things like create wallets, send and receive transactions, etc..

Thanks.

Comment: Since most Scrypt altcoins are a fork of Bitcoin, you can expect similar functionality and use similar tutorials and methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have a library in PHP for bitcoin transactions - https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php. It's mainly focussed on Bitcoin, and there are one or two places where hardcoded constants make dealing with altcoins tricky. That said, they are minor parts of the code.

(Only thing that comes to mind is if you're generating private keys just make sure you encode them to WIF's using BitcoinLib::base58_encode_checksum('privkey byte' . 'privkey hex'), passing the respective private key version byte, as the library will DEFAULT to using [address byte]+0x80 when generating addresses. This is how bitcoin does it, but it's not compatible with some coins, because they just use the first hex which gives the prefix they want)